# Linux File Append Operation

Tags: linux, file, append

Can anyone please explain how does file append in general work on linux?

For Example:
1.
File open in append mode
Write to file
Close file

2. File open in append mode
   Write to file
   Close file

when the 2nd operation is performed above, will the file be just appended without actually being erased?

The way the above operation is carried out will affect the flash wear-out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second operation will not erase the (first) file.
But it does move the data of the second file.

Erasing a file on any *nix system means removing the **inode** (which is just a pointer to where on the disk/ssd/flash the file actually starts.) The actual data  is not overwritten or even moved.

An example of inode data looks like this:

```
$ stat file.sh 
  File: ‘file.sh’
  Size: 289         Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 813h/2067d  Inode: 528981      Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-07-24 13:06:57.806899456 +0200
Modify: 2015-07-24 13:06:54.822899376 +0200
Change: 2015-07-24 13:06:54.822899376 +0200
 Birth: -
```

If it affects flash wear-out depends on the file size; if you have many very small files and lots of operations then the inodes can take up a few percent of the actual (disk/flash) size. If you have few operations (and perhaps large files) then I would not worry about flash wear out.

Answer (score 0):

> When the 2nd operation is performed above, will the file be just
>   appended without actually being erased?

File/Stream opening operations are implemented in Linux using `fopen()` for performing the required operations. See `man 3 fopen` for more info.

```
FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
```

The fopen() function opens the file whose name is the string pointed to by path and associates a stream with it.

The 2 modes for appending are :-

***a***    -----  Open  for  appending (writing at end of file).  The file is created if it does not exist.  The stream is positioned at the end of the file.

***a+***  -----   Open  for  reading  and appending (writing at end of file).  The file is created if it does not exist.  The initial file position for  reading  is  at the  beginning  of the file, but output is always appended to the end of the file.

> Opening a file in append mode (a as the first character of mode)
>   causes all subsequent write operations to this stream to occur at
>   end-of-file, as if preceded the call:
>
> ```
>  fseek(stream, 0, SEEK_END);
> ```

Also, the best way to open an existing file for appending and to create a file that doesn't exist is to make two separate calls to fopen(). The first call tries to append to the file. If that fails (when fopen() returns 0), then try opening the file using the "w" mode.

Check [this link on Append or Create a File Using fopen()](http://www.decompile.com/cpp/faq/fopen_write_append.htm) for more info .